# Chmod to change permissions for group

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chmod, tomcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting permissions for specific user and groups in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/144984/setting-permissions-for-specific-user-and-groups-in-linux)

I have put some users into a group and would like to know how I use chmod to change the access permissions for only the members of that group.
Thank you.

Comment: This may be of help - http://superuser.com/questions/144984/setting-permissions-for-specific-user-and-groups-in-linux

Comment: Are the files in that group?

Comment: -1 there is no research effort shown here, a simple look at `chmod --help` or manpages would have solved the problem. a google search would've yielded thousands of results and then it has been asked a lot of times here on superuser before.

Answer (score 2):

```
chmod g(+|-|=)<flags> [file ...]
```

Example:

```
chmod g+rw shared-file.txt
```

Comment: Doesn't that depend on whether the group has been given ownership of the file?

Comment: If a question has been answered elsewhere on the site, it is recommended that you flag it as a duplicate and not to respond with an answer.

Comment: PeanutsMonkey: Yes it does.

Randolph: Noted, thanks. Should I delete my answer then?

Comment: Don't delete your answer, it's good and fits the question. And until the question is not closed everone is free to answer it.