# ubuntu home folder permission

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have implemented openLDAP logging into my test server, each user has its own folder, which should be private for him.

Now I have testUser1, testUser2 and testUser3, that means my /home/ folder contains folders:

- testUser1_folder
- testUser2_folder
- testUser3_folder

Is there any way how to define, that testUser1_folder can be accessible only by root or testUser1?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you mean change permissions after creating the folders by hand, or automatically when the users are created? Both questions are very rtfmish.

Comment: I will, as a root, create theese folder by hand. But I don't know, how to assign to folders, they can be read only by certain users

Comment: I think you can make do without ACLs, but here is a possible solution: http://superuser.com/questions/144984/setting-permissions-for-specific-user-and-groups-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

Put this into your search engine of choice: "how manipulate folder ownership permissions unix"

you will find:

chown -R userY:grouX DIR - will change the ownership or a folder tree under DIR
chmod 750 DIR - will allow only users from groupX and userY to open DIR.

If you prefer technical documentation to google, there is `man chmod` and `man chown`.

Answer (score 1):

To change the directories you gave in your example type the following:

```
$ sudo chown -R testuser1:testuser1 /home/testUser1
$ sudo chown -R testuser2:testuser2 /home/testUser2
$ sudo chown -R testuser3:testuser3 /home/testUser3
```

Note this is basic unix/linux stuff, you might want to read some tutorials online or an Oreilly book like "[Linux in a nutshell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596154493.do?intcmp=ba-orm-books-int-search-linux-explore-ct)":